# SharePoint "online" (linked to item with edit menu); how to change

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to change the "link to edit" column in SharePoint ONLINE.  Please don't respond with non hosted SharePoint references.  There are plenty of examples out there for SharePoint fixes but not all of those options are out there for the hosted solutions.

Comment: What are the examples you have tried so far? Approach should be the same for both.

Comment: ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/contacts.png?rev=40" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="FirstName"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Name" LinkToItem="TRUE"/><FieldRef Name="WorkPhone"/><FieldRef Name="CellPhone"/><FieldRef Name="HomePhone"/><FieldRef Name="Alt_x0020_Phone_x0020_number"/><FieldRef Name="Alt_x0020_number_x0020_descripti"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><Aggregations Value="Off"/><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/>

Comment: trying to make name the edit link.  I add the below example and it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Let me try in my site

Answer (score 3):

Open your view page in designer like AlItems.aspx, then find your column and put a new attribute `LinkToItem="TRUE"`

```
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="Column Name" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>
</ViewFields>
```

Comment: does not work, see comments above.